# Best error handling approach for GPS lookup in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm beta testing my first Android app and have had a few users mention that when they attempt to lookup by GPS it hangs. In order to improve error handling around this I wanted to get the opinion of people who have apps in the wild.

My current activity does the following to kick off the lookup

```
findViewById(R.id.gpsButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    MyLocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

                    Criteria locationCriteria = new Criteria();
                    locationCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

                    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(mlocManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true), 0, 0, mlocListener);
                }
            });
```

The implementation of my custom location lookup class is below

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        private boolean alreadyLocatedDevice;
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public MyLocationListener() {
            this.dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LocationLookup.this, "", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
            DialogHelper.showDialogWithMessageAndTitle("", "You don't currently have location services turned on", LocationLookup.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
            if (!alreadyLocatedDevice) {
                alreadyLocatedDevice = true;
                Location loc = new Location();
                loc.setLng(Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));
                loc.setLat(Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));

                ((AppDelegate) getApplicationContext()).setSelectedLocation(loc);
                Intent findKioskLocation = new Intent(LocationLookup.this, FindKioskLocation.class);

                this.dialog.dismiss();

                startActivity(findKioskLocation);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
```

And finally I've added both the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions in my manifest file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might follow this thread -I found a mixture of my own approach (admittedly hackish in this code example) and the one mentioned by @bear to work without any issues (plus the location lookup was fast/accurate and error free)

I found the example listed by @bear to be a little more complex than I needed. For starters I wanted to kick off the GPS lookup when a button was clicked and have a simple async task wrapping this so it would throw up a dialog/etc

Next I wanted the exact latitude and longitude (no need to pass this off to another class because my example was simply to use the lat + lng to locate a resource and plot it)

So if you can follow my untested rather copy/paste approach here goes...

Inside your activity you would spin up the service during an onclick lets say ...

```
LocationManager networkManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationManager gpsManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

LocationService locationProcessor = new LocationService(YourActivityName.this, networkManager, gpsManager, dialog);
locationProcessor.onStartCommand();
```

Now the location service itself

```
package com.epicsoftware.android.global;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import com.epicsoftware.android.activity.LocationLookup;

public class LocationService {
    private LocationManager networkLm;
    private LocationManager gpsLm;
    private LocationListener networkListener;
    private LocationListener gpsListener;

    private boolean isRunning;
    private boolean networkLocDisabled;
    private boolean gpsLocDisabled;
    private Context activity;
    private LocationManager tmpNetworkManager;
    private LocationManager tmpGpsManager;
    private Handler locationHandler;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private boolean gpsUpdated;
    private boolean done;

    public LocationService(final Context activity, LocationManager networkManager, LocationManager gpsManager, ProgressDialog dialog) {
        this.tmpNetworkManager = networkManager;
        this.tmpGpsManager = gpsManager;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    public void onStartCommand() {
        if (!isRunning) {
            isRunning = true;

            startLocationListeners();

            locationHandler = new Handler();
            getLocationByZip.start();
        }
    }

    private void startLocationListeners() {
        networkListener = new NetworkLocationListener();
        gpsListener = new GpsLocationListener();

        networkLm = tmpNetworkManager;
        gpsLm = tmpGpsManager;

        networkLm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkListener);
        gpsLm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsListener);
    }


    private Thread getLocationByZip = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 15;) {
                    if (!locationDisabled() || !gpsUpdated) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            break;
                        }
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                locationHandler.post(monitorTheNetworkAndGpsProviders);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                killService();
                done = true;
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable monitorTheNetworkAndGpsProviders = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            killService();
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (!done) {
                done = true;
                ((LocationLookup) activity).warnUserThatLocationServicesAreDisabledOrFailed();
            }
        }
    };

    private boolean locationDisabled() {
        if (gpsLocDisabled && networkLocDisabled) {
            done = true;
            ((LocationLookup) activity).warnUserThatLocationServicesAreDisabledOrFailed();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void updateDb(Double lat, Double lon) {
        done = true;
        ((LocationLookup) activity).setLocationDataAndSpinUpNextActivity(lat, lon);
    }

    public void killService() {
        networkLm.removeUpdates(networkListener);
        gpsLm.removeUpdates(gpsListener);
    }

    public class NetworkLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                updateDb(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            networkLocDisabled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    public class GpsLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                gpsUpdated = true;
                updateDb(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            gpsLocDisabled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [nice](http://code.google.com/p/intexsoft/) implementation that I recnetly looked at. Basically by default it uses GPS to get a location. If no location can be found within a certain time period or no satellites are available it switches to Network.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

A Stacktrace from the logcat would have helped you and other developers here understand where the problem is coming from. Try to ask the users to recreate the problem if possible and find out when it is occurring.

As for guidance with the locaton manager, Google Developers just posted a blog recently and also updated the docs on how to use location manager. Check the [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) and also the [blog post which explains it with an example](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html). That might help you better. The blog post also explains how to use different location providers and how to be user friendly and guidance necessary in most ases when using location in Android applications.